# How to create a View with replication conflicts

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I wish to create a view showing a number of fields from notes documents with replication or save conflicts.  So far I have managed to create a basic view with a column for the document ID (Contract ID) then the next column states "Replication or Save Conflicts" but I don't seem to able to either get rid of the replocation or save conflcits column or add new columns to show additional fields from the document.  Is there a way I can do this?  I want to be able to show the view in XPages.  Here is the View selection formula I am using;

```
SELECT @IsAvailable($Conflict)
```

Answer (score 2):

Conflicts are not displayed good in views.  here are a few alternative tips to deal with conflicts that might give you an idea or two :-)

1. Create a categorized column with the value of the field $ConflictItems in the view you have, then you will see which item is causing the conflict and can take action to prevent it.
2. When you open a conflict you can use the action menu "View Parent" to compare the parent and the conflict
3. Ytra ScanEZ is a great tool for finding and resolving conflicts. it is also possible to create a script that will compare the documents and present a diff list.
4. You can create an XPage to display your conflicts (and parents). The web is more dynamic as it allow you to layout your data in the way you want and is not restricted to the way view in Notes works. This kind of xpage can be displayed in Notes client or Web browser

Comment: Thanks Thomas Option 4 sounds desirable as my aim is to allow the application administrator to see the view in Xpages web front end and have a delete button or delete check box for each one to allow the adminstrator the option to delete the conflict or the parent etc.  I am no expert in xpages and just maintaining an application developed by a former colleague

Comment: Do I start with a view using the formula I mentioned above but set up no columns in the view and then use Xpages to manipulate the view to show what I desire

Comment: I suggest you use a repeat in the xpage for finding the conflicts, lookup to view or using database.search(..:) and then two other nested repeat for displaying the values from the conflicts and the parent in the web ui

Comment: I did a quick xpage for viewing only, have a look here http://www.intrapages.com/thomas/xpagesconflict.nsf/start.xsp and contact me if you want the database

Comment: That looks quite useful.  If you wish you can send the database to a.farroll@btinternet.com  Thank you.  I will let you know how I get on

Answer (score 0):

Use XPages power. Get all documents from the view with your selection formula. But don't try to show any column value and get fields directly from back-end document you get from view entry `entry.getDocument()`.

Sure, it has some performance impact, but for (hopefully) small amount of replication conflict it's nothing serious.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you mean create the view with the Formula above but set up no columns and then in Xpages use the view in a custom control and use code like entry.getDocument() in the xpages to get the fields I desire